# Why is $M(p)/L_p $ a Dedekind p-group? (Where $M(p)/L$ is the p-Sylow of $G/L$)

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $T$-group (i.e. a group in which every subnormal subgroup is normal). Assume that $L$ is a normal abelian subgroup of odd order of $G$ and suppose that $G/L$ is a Dedekind group. Let now $L_p$ and $L_{p'}$ denote the Sylow $p-$ and Sylow $p'-$subgroups of L. Let $M(p)/L$ be the Sylow $p-$subgroup of $G/L$. Why is $M(p)/L_p'$ a Dedekind p-group?

This is a part of a proof of a theorem. It seems that $L$ has only a $p$-Sylow and a $p'$-Sylow, i.e. $|L|=p^k\cdot(p')^j$ for some positive natural $k,j$. Is it true? Why?

Comment: I would guess that $p$ is a fixed prime, $L_p$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $L$, and $L_{p'}$ is a complement of $L_p$ in $L$; i.e. the subgroup generated by the Sylow $q$-subgroups for all primes $q \ne p$. $M(p)/L_p$ is not even a $p$-group. You probably mean $M(p)/L_{p'}$.

Comment: Yes, it is $M(p)/L_{p'}$. I read well the answer and let you know in few minutes!

Comment: This means that, because $L$ is abelian, $L_{p'}$ is the product of the $q$-Sylow of $L$, for $q \neq p$, right?

Comment: Yes. Note that $M(p)/L_{p'}$ is a $p$-group, so all of its subgroups are subnormal, but it is also a $T$-group, so they are all normal.

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything works!